# Where is configure in libpng?

Tags: caffe, libpng

I was installing Caffe and ran into an error:

> make all CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin
>   //home/ivan/anaconda3/lib/libpng16.so.16: undefined reference to
>   `inflateValidate@ZLIB_1.2.9' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status Makefile:625: recipe for target
>   '.build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin' failed make: ***
>   [.build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin] Error 1

the possible solution is to run `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/`, however, which configure is it about, and where can I find it?

Comment: configure is inside your root folder, same place where you are running your make all command,it should come with caffe

Comment: >ivan@ivan-Lenovo-G780 ~/Downloads/caffe $ ls
build            data        INSTALL.md               models
caffe.cloc       distribute  LICENSE                  python
cmake            docker      Makefile                 README.md
CMakeLists.txt   docs        Makefile.config          scripts
CONTRIBUTING.md  examples    Makefile.config.example  src
CONTRIBUTORS.md  include     matlab                   tools
>ivan@ivan-Lenovo-G780 ~/Downloads/caffe $ ./configure
>bash: ./configure: No such file or directory